# create a route without prefix in strapi v4

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, strapi

I am using `strapi` v4 and i want to implement stripe in it and use web-hooks , i want to create a route that has no prefix like **`/API`** or `/<content-type-name>` like `localhost:1337/web-hook` but in the custom routes its created as `localhost:1337/API/web-hook`

tried this :

```
   routes:[
    {
        method: "POST",
        path: "/web-hook",
        handler: "api::order.order.webHooks"
    }
]
```

Comment: I can know the reason behind ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!